# How to find functions, classes and IDs on HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Intro:** I am fixing a website that wasn't coded by me (first time) and I would like to know the best way to find functions, classes and IDs associations within all files of the website.

**Main problem:** The main problem is that I lose too much time trying do discover what function does what and what elements are affected. For example I look at a certain element with a certain ID or class and I have to manually search all files to check associations.

**Extra info:** I currently use sublimetext and, some times, dreamweaver but I am willing to use other programs if needed to be more efficient. The website is mainly HTML, CSS and Javascript.

**Example:** ID="affected" was modified by file_1.js and file_7.js. **Or** ID="affected" is using style_1.css which is being target by file_5.js. I am not sure if there is such a software though.

**Update:**
1) I still have to test Sadi Qevani answer but so far I've concluded the following:
2) NetBeans is good for javascript but it requires an install to do something that sublimetext or notepad++ already do. For example I can add folders and/or files to sublimetext press ctrl+shift+f and find any word in all files, it will show the files and some of the code near the word in that file, click twice and I am editing that file in the exact line of code where the word appears. This can be used to every type of file!
3) Chrome and Firefox with firebug are excelent tools to check the CSS of each element and to test some changes without touching the original files.
4) I was expecting a powerfull program that would "think" like a browser to show everything that is happening when a browser opens "line-by-line" so I know which element was being affected by whom and so on... but maybe it doesn't even exists :(

Comment: `ack` lets you search for code in a directory recursively, and I imagine it allows you to use regular expressions. At the least you should be able to run `ack #` and get some IDs.

Comment: If it is a php site, might aswell use an IDE that support intellisense. For example phpstorm or zend studio allow you to see the function definition right by hovering on them. It also shows you the file where it is located

Comment: Could you give more detailed example suing specific code of the kind of association that is giving you trouble: unpicking someone elses code is always difficult, that is why good practice is to use many comments

Comment: I don't think you can do anything to ease the pain of fixing spaghetti code other than what Waleed Khan mentioned above, look for patterns.

Comment: This is called developing.  Aka, the reason we're all employed.

Comment: Dreamweaver does have an option to search the source of files within a specified directory.

Comment: Yes I know but I was trying to look for some software that would allow to know everything that is affecting an element. Example: ID="affected" was modified by file_1.js and file_7.js. Or ID="affected" is using style_1.css which is being target by file_5.js. I am not sure if there is such a software though.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that helps me is to use Chrome and right-click on an element, and then select 'Inspect Element'. That brings up the Web Inspector, and from there I can see extra details on the element. (I can also play with those details to see how they change the element).

Once I have a specific class or id I search the code for references to that. In sublime text I believe that shift + command + f will bring up the search menu. From there you should be able to see references to that class or id.

It may be helpful for you to investigate source mapping in Chrome. If properly configured this will allow you to make live changes to your code from within Chrome. This saves the step of having to search for where the element's styles are defined. This is more useful if you're dealing with a set of static files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, although not the best browser, Firefox has an excellent debugger for JavaScript called firebug. Safari has something similar as well and all three of these have an 'inspect element' feature like Martin said, that is a great way to see the relevant IDs and Classes. So if you don't have Chrome, you can still use the inspect element feature

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at this and comment later. Shif + cmd + F = what in windows? Do you think it's possible to do what I put in the example above? (I edited to try to insert an example. Don't know if it's too clear so any suggestions would be good to improve the initial post).

Comment: This answer is very good to check CSS but it doesn't solve my all question.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from browser tools, the best tool for that would be NetBeans. After installation, create a project with your current website's directory and navigate to any one of the files within that directory. Once you have a file open, right click on an ID or class and hit "find declaration." Works like a charm.

Comment: This answer is good but it requires installing NetBeans :( I prefer using sublimetext where you can add folders and search a certain string within files and/or folders with ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver and Sublime do not provide a good Code Sniffer tool.

What i am using and what i would suggest to everyone is using webStorm or phpStorm.

With webStorm, holding the CTRL key and clicking on the function, it will re-direct you to the function file/location.

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: That is used for java only? I will try to take a look at this and comment later. Can I easily see what elements are being affected by a java function? Or the CTRL + Right Click is just a "Go To" function definition when clicking on the function call?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple tools that can help you find what you're looking for. When used in combination, I'm sure you'll be ready to rock 'n roll.

First things first, checkout Google Chrome's console and developer tools by right clicking on any element on the web page and selecting "Inspect Element".

The first thing you'll see is the element gets highlighted in blue, with padding and margins highlighted in other colors. You should also see a tabbed pane slide up from the bottom. You can use the Sources tab to see which javascript files are used on the page, and the Console tab to see any errors that the current code throws.

One thing to consider while debugging is using console.log() to test changes you make to the javascript code. If you're creating an object and need to see if the browser is hitting that part of the code, you can type (in the function, in the source file) console.log()

Then, when you refresh the browser, you will see the object in the Console and all of its properties. If you see nothing, that means the browser isn't hitting your/their function. This will also be a good way to see what a function does if its even getting called.

Another tool you can use is grep if you have a Linux or Unix box like Mac OS (I believe there is a similar tool called FINDSTR). Fire up terminal and a simple way to see which files in a directory contain a given string, cd into the directory and type: grep -r StringToSearch *

This will recursively search the directory and any child directories for the string you type in place of "StringToSearch".

If you want to get more information from grep, please see the documentation for ways to get grep to return more detailed information like the specific line the string appears in.  http://ibm.co/18zWfaX <-- has exhaustive documentation.

Comment: Well dreamweaver and sublimetext also have a "find in directory" but it isn't as smooth as I would like it to be. But my main problem isn't just about finding a certain string within a directory. Please check the example I edited in the initial post to see if what you suggested would solve the issue. Probably what I am looking for doesn't even exists...

Comment: @jetsetter seems to have a viable answer for your updated question. I'm generally not a proponent of NetBeans, but this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac or some Linux distro, you can use `grep` to search for any word in all files. Grep means 'general regular expression parser' and does find expressions inside files for you. For example:

```
  $ grep 'random-word' home/mary/*.css
```

It will look for the string 'random-word' in all css files in the /home/mary/ folder. Here is some [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html).

If you use Windows, you can replace grep for `findstr`. There is [an article](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/cmd/findstr.html) explaining how to make it.